# printing navigation subform in ms access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I recently created a database application in MS Access 2010 using navigation subforms.  The users of this database are used to printing out forms with data from individual records.  The navigation subforms cannot be printed in MS Access 2010.  I read that I should use reports for printing individual records, and I am in the midst of creating reports for each of the forms.  The task of creating all the reports is so laborious that I am concerned about the ability to maintain the database over time.  Whenever we change a form, we will also have to change the corresponding report, because both look identical.

Can someone suggest a better way of letting users print out the contents of forms for individual records in an application in which the forms are nested in navigation subforms?

It occurs to me that vba could create an instance of a stand-alone form and print it when a control is clicked in the nested form.  Ideally, this might happen behind the scenes, without the form ever becoming visible.  This would cut the work of making changes to forms in half.  But how would it look in code?  Are there reasons not to do this? Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: What you're doing creating the reports is probably best. You might be able to contrive something programmatically as per your last paragraph, but actually pulling it off, and making it look nice enough to do the job consistently for all the forms is likely to be harder and more time consuming that creating the reports.

Comment: So, I have an idea, but it would be rather laborious to figure it out.  See [this msdn article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161299/EN-US).  Basically, it's a screen X and Y targeted Print Screen through the win32 API that gets you an in-memory bmp.  Because VBA doesn't have all of the enums available to VB, you would have to define ones for [StdPicture Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243033(v=vs.60).aspx) and [RasterOp Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243035(v=vs.60).aspx).  I'm not sure about the printing part yet...